# How to print Python array within HTML email body?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I have a Python function that returns an array. I'd like to print the array within the body of a HTML email but I can't figure out how to execute Python within HTML.
This is the HTML element of my email script...

```
html = """<html>
<head></head>
<body>    
<p>These are the available dates: </p>
<%= avDates() %>
</body>
</html>
"""
```

...the email executes fine, I'm receiving mail, but the function prints out as text ("<%= avDates() %>" is shown in the email). 
How do I get this to work?

***Update***
I've changed the code to the following as per @Francesco's suggestion - it makes sense to me but the script now sends me a black email body (contains one " character) and the array is sent to the shell...

```
date_list = avDates()
date_list_string = ' '.join(date_list)
html = """<html>
<head></head>
<body>    
<p>These are the available dates: </p>
""" + date_list_string + """"
</body>
</html>
"""
```

Comment: use [format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) (or if you need better html rendering use a library like jinja2)

Comment: You need to include the part of the code that's sending the email

Comment: The email functions correctly, as does the array function - I just can't get the array to print in the email body with the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would construct a string with the dates and then insert into your html:

```
date_list = avDates()
date_list_string = ' '.join(date_list) # edit this to match the desired output

html = """<html>
<head></head>
<body>    
<p>These are the available dates: </p>
""" + date_list_string + """"
</body>
</html>
"""
```

Comment: That makes sense to me but when I try it, I get a blank email and the array shows in the shell window

Comment: You should update your question with the new code you wrote so that we can help you with that

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the array and not with the email script - I'm going to close this and post a different question.